# Measure of an arc

Tags: geometry

how would you doing the measure of the arc? I have tried finding the radius.

[image]

Comment: The problem *gives* the radius. What you need to find is the angle subtended by $CD$.

Comment: @dxiv exactly, OP has tried finding the radius... on the page.  There it is!

Answer (score 0):

The angle inside the triangle at the centre of the circle has a sine given by 36.7 divided by two, divided by 21.6, meaning that the angle is 57.32465 degrees, or 1 radian.  Therefore the arc length is twice r*theta, which is 43.2inches.